# Найти первый неодинаковый символ в 2 строках

Tags: python

Задача: найти первый неодинаковый символ в 2 строках, нужно сделать без всяких встроенных модулей на *python*.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне учесть всё, что я не учёл в коде:

```
def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
"""
Inputs:
  line1 - first single line string
  line2 - second single line string
Output:
  Returns the index where the first difference between
  line1 and line2 occurs.

  Returns IDENTICAL if the two lines are the same.
"""
#min_len = len(line1) if len(line1)< len(line2) else len(line2)

if len(line1) <= len(line2):
    min_len = line1
else:
    min_len = line2

for i in range(len(min_len)):
    if line1[i] != line2[i]:
        return (i)

    elif len(line1) != len(line2):
        return len(min_len)
    else:
        return IDENTICAL
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, можно пример ввода/вывода?

Comment: line1 = "Python is fun!", line2 = "Python i fun!"

Comment: А вывод какой будет? И сразу дайте пример если строке не равны по длине и не нашелся нужный результат

Answer (score 0):

```
def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
  if len(line1) <= len(line2):
    min_len = len(line1)
  else:
    min_len = len(line2)

  # сначала проверим символы до конца короткой строки  
  for i in range(min_len):
    if line1[i] != line2[i]:
      return (i)
  # если в какой-то строке остались символы, первый из них и есть несовпавший 
  if len(line1) != len(line2):
    return min_len
  # длины тоже равны, значит строки одинаковые
  return "IDENTICAL"
```

Comment: спасибо, но тут тоже ошибка (попробуйте line1 = "Pyhton is fun!", line2 = "Python i fun!" выдаст не корректное значение :((((

Comment: питон одинаково напишите, будет не 2, а больше

Comment: оказывается, eval умеет питон - https://eval.in/910805 А как комментарии писать - он ругается :) ?

Comment: line1 = "Pythрon is fun!", line2 = "Python i fun!" выдает значение 14, а должно выдать 9 :((((

Comment: пойдите по моей ссылке и попробуйте - все отлично

Comment: Все понял ошибку спасибо большое :))))

Comment: Кстати, искать минимальную длину можно так: `min_length = min(map(lambda x: len(x), (line1, line2)))` автору вопроса на заметку.

Comment: @Alban можно и так -  `min_len = min(len(line1), len(line2))`  но он же все руками хочет

Comment: @splash58 у всех свои тараканы :) Можно с `zip()` скомбинировать и однострочник написать :)

Comment: @Alban я не очень понял ваш комментарий, наверное потому, что я на питоне не умею просто совсем. Про мин я попробовал на eval - оно сработало :)

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! Да, вы правы, есть куча, вариантов более эффективных с различными методами и модулями, просто в задании нужно ручками ((((( Еще раз большое спасибо за помощь!